# jsTree drag item disintegration

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jstree

I'm dynamically creating some elements that should be drop-able onto a JSTree component. The tree is configured and the drag process is working, it's just not working as one would expect.

Take this HTML fragment:

```
<div id="newDragEntry_1" class="newDragEntry">
  <div class="floatLeft">
    <span class="newEntryThumbtab">#</span>
    <span class="newEntryLabel">asdfasdf</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floatRight">
    <span class="newEntryFilename">(LICENSE)</span>
    <span id="newEntryIcon_1" class="newEntryIcon">
      <img src="/img/lib/icons/mime/pdf.png">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is a container div assigned a class of "newDragEntry" - and that is what the jsTree is configured to recognize. The problem is that whichever inner-element a user happens to grab when they initiate the drag becomes the actual drag object. So, if they grab the text "LICENSE" then that's what gets ghosted and dragged -- rather than the entire #newDragEntry_1 element (which just resembles a button when styled-out.)

Anyone got any ideas?

(FWIW - I can get the drag behavior I'm looking for by using jq's .draggable() method directly, but then I don't seem to get any drop events fired by jstree?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a pile of digging I've come to the conclusion that the solution to this problem would require a codebase modification within jsTree OR a healthy dose of manual event tracking (ie., your own superimposed drag logic.)

If anyone finds themselves here looking for a resolution, the place to start is this snip from the jstree sourcecode (version : jsTree 1.0-rc3):

```
var s = this._get_settings().dnd;
if(s.drag_target) {
  $(document)
    .delegate(s.drag_target, "mousedown.jstree-" + this.get_index(), $.proxy(function (e) {
  o = e.target;
  $.vakata.dnd.drag_start(e, { jstree : true, obj : e.target }, "<ins class='jstree-icon'></ins>" + $(e.target).text() );
```

The last line is the important one. At the end you'll see that it is extracting the TEXT from the bubbled drag event originator - hence the disintegration of a composite  like my example above. This means that any stylized formatting will be excluded from the ghost helper (among other things).

My solution: not very elegant to be sure, but I had to redo the composition of the drag source so that only a smaller text-based portion was jstree-draggable.